# My App widget's Remoteview's receiver getting call randomly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget, android-pendingintent, appwidgetprovider

I am beginner in working with app widget. Here i have made one app widget of app and in its class set receiver on click of widget icon.Its working when user clicks on it.But the issue is receiver also gets called sometimes automatically.
I am not getting why this is happening.Help will be appreciated.

My app widget's class:

**MyWidget.java:**

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static Context cont;
    static SharedPreferences preferences;


    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cont = context;
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.
                getBroadcast(context, 0,
                        intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget_text, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("key", true).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferences.edit().putBoolean("key", false).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="*************************">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".Myservice" />
      <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"></receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MyWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="**********************" />
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/my_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: @David Wasser - I have added manifest file..please check it out..

Comment: Look at your _info.xml file. You have there updatePeriodMillis:"XXX" that called.

Comment: @Kram- i already gave "86400000" in updatePeriodMillis.But its still calls my remoteview's click listener's receiver  randomly.

Comment: is anyone having answer on this?

Comment: @Devop it's rly strange that your receiver getting triggered. Try to add action in intent for receiver and in receiver checks it like that (intent.getAction().equals("YOUR_ACTION"))